# Defining dA in a Double Integral

Tags: integration, analysis

Suppose I have this region:

[image: Image of region]

and I want to calculate
$$
\int \int_A x_3^2 dA
$$
From my understanding, this is equal to
$$
2\cdot \int_0^a \int_0^{x_3} x_3^2 \ dx_3 \ dx_2 = 2\cdot\int_0^a \frac{1}{3}x_3^3 \ dx_2
$$

Which could be calculated knowing $x_3(x_2)$

My question is, why do I have to consider $dA = dx_2  dx_3$, when I can simply say that $dA = dx_2  x_3(x_2)$. Wouldn't the infinite double summation of infinitely small cubes be the same thing as the summation of infinitely small rectangles?

The second approach would give another solution

$$
\int \int_A x_3^2 dA = \int_0^h x_3^2 x_2 \ dx_2
$$

---

EDIT: The problem asks to calculate $\int \int x_3^2 \ dA$ and $\int \int x_2^2 \ dA$, knowing that $x_3(x_2) = h\cdot (1-\frac{x_2^2}{a^2})$ and $x_2(x_3) = a\cdot \sqrt{1-\frac{x_2}{a}}$

The solutions seem to be (which give the right final answers)

$$
\int \int_A  x_3^2\ dA = 2 \int_0^a \frac{x_3^3}{3} \ dx_2 = \frac{32}{105}ah^3
$$

and

$$
\int \int_A x_2^2 \ dA = 2 \int_0^a x_2^2 \cdot x_3 \ dx_2 = \frac{4}{15} a^3 h
$$

---

EDIT 2: It seems that I misunderstood the whole point of the exercise, as $x_3^2$ is not a function $f(x_2, x_3)$ but only a function of $x_3$ (even if $x_3$ itself is a function of $x_2$ for defining the region), so the second approach works just fine.

So after my basic understanding, the statemant that the sum of infinitely small rectangles $=$ double sum of infinitely small squares is only true in $\mathbb R^2$, not in $\mathbb R^3$ (where a $f(x_2,x_3)$ would appear).

Comment: What is the precise definition of the region $A$ given in your exercise?

Comment: You would be basically correct, if the integral was $\iint1dA$. But the density $x_3^2$ changes things; you're not finding just the area of $A$.

Comment: @RobertZ Sorry for the inconvenience. See the edit I just made

Comment: $x_3$ is not a function of $x_2$. The values it can take on are limited by the value of $x_2$, but that is a far cry from actually being determined by the value of $x_2$ - that is, if you know the value of $x_2$, you could figure out the value of $x_3$ from it. That is what "x_3 is a function of $x_2$" means. But here, knowing $x_2$ still leaves $x_3$ free to take on any value within an interval.

Comment: But you are correct that if $f(x,y) \ge 0$ for all $(x,y) \in A$, then $\iint_A f(x,y)\,dxdy = \iiint_B 1\,dxdydz$, where $B = \{(x,y,z) : (x,y) \in A, 0 \le z \le f(x,y)\}$ assuming the integrals exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, $x_3^2$ is not a function of $x_2$. The values of $x_3$ are limited by the values of $x_2$ and vice-verse (i.e. for defining the region), but that is not the same thing. That indeed makes

$$\int_{0}^{h} x_2^2 x_3 \, dx_2 = \int_0^a \dfrac{1}{3}x_3^3 \, dx_2$$

So the problem is actually in $2D$ (where the infinite double summation of infinitely small squares is the same infinite summation of infinitely thin rectangles), but in $3D$, where an actual $f(x_2, x_3)$ would appear, the statement becomes false (with cubes and rectangular cuboids this time).